# selenium (find_by_id) method doesn't work inside a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I wrote this code to simulate some clicks to get citations from a google scholar page.

```
 def APAcite (papers):
    gscholar= 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=' 
    cites = []
    for p in papers:
        print(p)
        address = gscholar + p
        Nbrowser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_p) 
        Nbrowser.get(address) 
        Nbrowser.find_element_by_link_text('Cite').click()
        APA = Nbrowser.find_element_by_id('gs_cit1').click()
        Bib = Nbrowser.find_element_by_link_text('BibTeX').click()
        cit_pg = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('''body > pre''')
        cites.append(cit_pg.text)
        Nbrowser.close()
    return cites
```

Then I defined a list of papers

```
l = ['Sustainability and the measurement of wealth: further reflections']
```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-309-4208af266f79> in APAcite(papers)
      8         Nbrowser.get(address)
      9         Nbrowser.find_element_by_link_text('Cite').click()
---> 10         APA = Nbrowser.find_element_by_id('gs_cit1').click()
     11         Bib = Nbrowser.find_element_by_link_text('BibTeX').click()
     12         cit_pg = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('''body > pre''')
```

.
.
.

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"gs_cit1"}
```

Although I inspect the page and get sure that this id exists
[id for selected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSnQ4.png)

Another point, when I run the code outside the function and without the `for` loop, I don't get any errors and it works fine!

Can you please help in that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line of code

```
Nbrowser.implicitly_wait(20)
```

After

```
Nbrowser.get(address)
```

Basically you are moving too fast. After the click it takes some time for the text to appear and you try to find the id which is not there (yet!)

I get below output after fixing the code

> Sustainability and the measurement of wealth: further reflections
>   ['@article{arrow2013sustainability,\n  title={Sustainability and the measurement of wealth: further reflections},\n  author={Arrow, Kenneth J and Dasgupta, Partha and Goulder, Lawrence H and Mumford, Kevin J and Oleson, Kirsten},\n  journal={Environment and Development Economics},\n  volume={18},\n  number={4},\n  pages={504--516},\n  year={2013},\n  publisher={Cambridge University Press}\n}']

Comment: Don't use implicit wait. It's a bad practice. Instead add an explicit wait, e.g. wait for that element to be clickable and then click it and it will work.